# Как сохранить параметр в Yii::$app->params из кода?

Tags: yii2

Как сохранить параметр в Yii::$app->params из кода?
Yii::$app->params['test'] ='новое значение' не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Массив `Yii::$app->params` фреймворк получает из конфига. Для того, что бы params можно было изменять из кода, надо либо изменять файл конфигурации из кода, что совершенно не хорошо, либо получать params из базы данных, например. Для этого нужно написать компонент, получающий массив из бд и инициализировать его в секции bootstrap.